# Unable to activate Office 365, because cookies are blocked

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, office365, windows-server-2012-r2

I've installed Office 365 on a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine with IESC enabled. When trying to activate Office it prompts me to sign in and as soon as I enter an email address it says:

> Cookies must be allowed
>
> Your browser is currently set to block
>   cookies. Your browser must allow cookies before you can use a
>   Microsoft account.
>
> Cookies are small text files stored on your computer that tell
>   Microsoft sites and services when you're signed in. To learn how to
>   allow cookies, see online help in your web browser.

It says this even if I set Internet Options, Privacy to "Accept All Cookies" or  check "Override automatic cookie handling" and select "Accept" for both first-party and third-party cookies.

What do I need to do to allow Office to activate?

Comment: You probably need to add the site to your trusted sites when enhanced security is enabled.

Comment: I've tried, but I don't know what "the site" is. I've added a few guesses like *.microsoftonline.com, *.live.com, *.windows.net, but it hasn't helped.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is customer service-related and not a programming question.

Comment: Even though it is customer-service related and it was right to close it, I found it helpful.

Answer (score 31):

I spent way too much time on this silly issue. Following any **one** of the following bullet points may fix this for you. Pick one that you like:

- Open Internet Explorer. From the Settings (gear) menu, select Internet Options/Privacy Tab/Settings Advanced Button. Notice that the `Third-party cookies` radio button says "Accept"? Click "Block", Click "Accept" and then Ok, Ok your way out. Yes, you are setting it right back to where it started! Each user needs to do this separately.
- As similarly answered by Danny adding https://*.microsoftonline.com to the trusted sites in Internet Options fixes this issue. I know some others are reporting this doesn't work but it works for me with Server 2016. The correct entry can be discovered by using the [nirsoft dnsquerysniffer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dns_query_sniffer.html) during the office 365 login process. Here's some PowerShell to create a registry entry.  The nice part about this registry entry is that it seems to fix this issue for all users.

  ```
  $regPath = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\EscDomains\microsoftonline.com'
  $regProperty = 'https'
  $regValue = '2'
  New-Item -Path $regPath -Force -Verbose
  New-ItemProperty -Path $regPath -Name $regProperty -Value $regValue -Force -Verbose -Type DWord
  ```
- Set `HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3\1A10` to 1. Note you will have to do this for each user so this may be a good solution for those of you who can control user registry properties through group policy or other means.

Comment: First one was the good one. It was on Windows Server ... So horrible when it comes to configure IE Settings ...

Comment: The first one worked for me as well. Windows Server 2016.

Comment: First one worked for me. Windows Server 2016.

Comment: First one. There's no reason this should work but it does. ‍♂️

Answer (score 3):

The first bullet point from [BradT's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44034811/3546415) was half the problem for me and extremely non-obvious. The other half was unchecking "Enable Protected Mode" under Security for "Internet".

I was able to reproduce the problem by checking "Enable protected Mode". Once checked, even if I unchecked it, the problem persisted until I repeated the radio button reset for third party cookies. This means that the order of operation matters for these two actions. Resetting your security/Internet options to "Default level" enables protected mode, and so will recreate this problem until protected mode is unchecked and the radio button reset.

I didn't need to add any site to trusted sites. The actions below seemed to be all that was needed for me.

***1.) Security --> Internet --> Uncheck Protected Mode***

[image: Security Internet Uncheck Protected Mode]

***2.) Reset Third-Party Cookies Enabled by deselected and re-selecting the radio button***

[image: Reset Third-Party Cookies Enabled]

This non-obvious usage blocking out-of-the-box incompatibility seems ridiculous... and the funny thing is since it's Microsoft I just shrug.

Answer (score 2):

Got it finally working for mine. I hope yours works too using the below method.

Open regedit.exe

navigate to:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\
SOFTWARE\
Policies\
Microsoft\
Windows\
CurrentVersion\
Internet Settings\
ZoneMapKey

then on the right hand side, right click and add 'String Value' and name with the below sites and then enter AND THEN double click on their name and enter 'Data Value' 2

*.microsoft.com 
*.microsoftonline.com 
*.office.com 
*.visualstudio.com 
*.live.com

and also on my internet explorer > tools >  internet options 
security tab: internet (uncheck - Enable Protected Mode ...)
privacy tab: settings bar to Medium and then click on 'sites' and add the above list of sites. Thats it. good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and I manage to resolve it by following most of the suggested steps.

I added the following sites as trusted sites, without knowing if all in fact was required, but it works:

- http://*.microsoftonline.com
- *.microsoftonline.com
- *.office.net
- *.microsoft.com

Then I unselected the "Enable projection mode.."

Finally restarted the browser and restarted Outlook

First i managed to login, but not to activate.

Then I had to restart Outlook, and next time i could activate. However the activate sign stay on as it is not done or not working.

Then i restart Outlook again and finally it is ok.

Answer (score 0):

It's https://login.microsoftonline.com, had the same issue as you activating Office 2016 on Windows Server 2016, hope this helps.

Comment: I tried that - added http and https for login.microsoftonline.com, *.microsoftonline.com and for good measure *.live.com and *.windows.net, but still get the same error message. :(

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to login to Windows 365 with this same problem. Searched for online answers, messed around with every setting, but I finally fixed it today! I had enabled third party cookies and everything, but just figured out what was still not working. This may not help everyone, but I:

1) switched my default to internet explorer
2) In explorer, I clicked on settings, privacy, sites
3) In the list of sites, I realized "live.com" was set to "blocked", which made it impossible for office to communicate. At some point had added it, but meant to allow rather than block.
4) Opened an office program, and was finally able to sign in.

After doing this, I also switched my default browser back to my preferred one and everything still worked fine. Hope this helps somebody out there - I was racking my brain!